# Conditionally inclusion of bean in XML?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have below bean definition in my spring XML.

I want to include it conditionally if specific property is true

```
If includeCustomBean==true

   <bean id="message"
                     class="com.CustomReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    </bean>

else

    <bean id="message"
                     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    </bean>
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4):

you can use Spring expression language just like below example.

```
<bean class="com.example.MyBean">
 <property name="dependency" value="#{systemProperties['foo'] == 'bar' 
 ? dependencyX : dependencyY}" />
 </bean>
```

or profile is another concept

https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml